# Confusing double angle identity

Tags: trigonometry

How would I solve the following double angle identity.

$$\cos^4x=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{8}\cos(4x)$$

So far my work is

$$\frac{3}{8}+\frac{2\cos^x-1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}(2\cos^2x-1)$$

But how would I proceed.

Comment: Is "indentity" the new, cool way to spell that word these days?

Comment: I thought spell check correct it....... I think its spelled correctly.

Comment: Off course which a spell chequer you can knot have any Miss spellings. :-) (BTW, *my* spell checker tells me "indentity" is wrong).

Comment: how is it spelled?

Comment: Use latex. Is it $\cos^4 x = \frac{3}{8} + \frac{1}{2}\cos 2x + \frac{1}{8}\cos 4x$? Where did you get $\cos^x$ in your work?

Comment: It is spelled "identity", without an "n" after the "i".

Comment: yes karolis that is except that there is cos(4x) at the end.

Comment: I meant 2cos^2x-1 like is the indentity.

Comment: and for the second one I meant (1/8)(2cos^2 2x-1)

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Please fix those typos in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that 
\begin{eqnarray}
\cos(2x)&=& \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x \\
&=& 2 \cos^2 x - 1.\\
\end{eqnarray}
Then
\begin{equation}
\cos^2 x = \dfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x)).
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{eqnarray}
\cos^4 x &=& (\cos^2 x)^2\\
&=& \left[\dfrac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2x))\right]^2\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{4}(1 +2 \cos(2x)+ \cos^2(2x))\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{4} +\dfrac{1}{2} \cos(2x) + \dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\cos(4x))\\
&=& 3/8 + 1/2 \cos(2x) +1/8 \cos(4x)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I never knew the problem could be done in such a way.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\cos^4(x) &= \left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^4\\
 &= \frac{e^{4xi} + 4e^{2xi} + 6 + 4e^{-2xi} + e^{-4xi}}{16}\\
 &= \frac{3}{8} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{2xi} + e^{-2xi}}{2} + \frac{1}{8} \frac{e^{4xi}+e^{-4xi}}{2}\\
 &= \frac{3}{8} + \frac{1}{2} \cos(2x) + \frac{1}{8} \cos(4x)
\end{align*}

Comment: Complex methods may not be what the OP had in mind, but they are a marvelous tool (+1).